# Should pcall catch PANIC errors (ESP32 NodeMCU)?

Tags: nodemcu, esp32

I've such code:

```
print("AAAAAA")
local status, jobj = pcall(json.decode(docTxt))
print("BBBBBB")
```

`decode` method causes PANIC error, an it results in following console output:

```
AAAAAAA
PANIC: unprotected error in call to Lua API (json.lua:166: 'for' initial value must be a number)
```

Whole program beaks, `BBBBB` does not get printed to console.

Is this normal? Is `pcall` broken ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure it out: it can be configured in watchdog options for firmware compiler. Now I've have such setup, that it reboots on panic.